# How to iterate throguh all possible combinations in an array using recursion?

Tags: arrays, recursion

I have started to learn recursion and I find it very confusing when I was solving a practice problem.

For example, if I have an array in sorted order `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and I want to iterate through all possible combinations of `d` jumps starting from the first number `2` till end number `9`.

Some of the valid jumps are (for d = 3 jumps):

2->3->5->9

2->3->6->9

2->3->7->9

2->3->8->9

2->4->5->9

and so on.

Please tell me how to approach such recursion problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem reduces quickly: remove both ends of the list.  Now, all you have to do is choose **d-1** elements from the remaining list.  Finding all combinations of **m** elements in a list of length **n > m** is easily researched.  You can almost certainly find a solution in your favorite language.

Does that insight get you moving?

Comment: Thanks, solved that problem now. Recursion could be very confusing sometimes. Especially, for a novice like me.

Comment: No kidding.  recursive combination and permutation code is readily available in most popular languages.  Of you want notes on recursion in general, search on SO or the Internet as a whole, for "recursion explain base case".  That should give you a high proportion of useful hits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a class that calculates possible hops:

```
public class HopCalculator {

  private int[] input;

  public HopCalculator(int[] input) {
    this.input = input;
  }
```

The input array was given in construction time. Now we can query different routes with different lengths (number of hops).
The output is a Set that contains possible routes.
Each route is an array-list that contains the number it goes through.

```
  public Set<ArrayList<Integer>> findPossibleHops(int d) {
    Set<ArrayList<Integer>> options = new HashSet<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> option = new ArrayList<>();
    option.add(input[0]);

    findPossibleHopsRecursive(options, option, d-1, 1, input.length-2);
    return options;
  }

  private void findPossibleHopsRecursive(Set<ArrayList<Integer>> options, ArrayList<Integer> option, int d, int begin, int end) {
    if (d==0) {
        option.add(input[end+1]);
        options.add(option);
    }
    else {
        if (end - begin + 1 == d) {
            option.add(input[begin]);
            findPossibleHopsRecursive(options, option, d - 1, begin + 1, end);
        } else {
            ArrayList<Integer> option1 = new ArrayList<>();
            option1.addAll(option);
            option1.add(input[begin]);
            findPossibleHopsRecursive(options, option1, d - 1, begin + 1, end);

            ArrayList<Integer> option2 = new ArrayList<>();
            option2.addAll(option);
            findPossibleHopsRecursive(options, option2, d, begin + 1, end);
        }
    }
  }
}
```